# response.text returning bytes and weird symbols

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a site
`url = 'https://spar.pl/gazetka/spar/'`,
and trying in either console or VS Code:

```
requests.get(url).text
```

returns a jumble of bytes and other symbols unknown to me. The example of how it starts:

```
`\x139��HM�!�\x11:|�{R�����-z\x08~+�O\x00�\x14Ʌ<λ����dk4 \x00R�(�\x0bPɲ.Ģ��Eu��n���/_M�L�\x14�X�ܪt-������\x07�||��\x07��\x00��\x0c\x08:�i�T�ݿ\x7f?\x08�\'\x1c��I!�\x14\x03\x15R�\\�n\x15b\'���\x14�N���+�(��������\u05c9\x04HB\x08�hou\x0c�~/~�v���9ԯ?g��"�sZ\x13# ��j\r*�j)�K|�\x19NZ��s�\r��N�q����=x\x05�\x0b��2�0\x05���V�\x7f��������\x02�}���\x18Pl�aU����\'\x1d˷N�a`�\x0f���:���w&\x0b�\t��5���Y-fВ\x14\x10�?��\x17\x0f\r\x11�s��%n`
```

Oddly enough, when I try the same code in  Jupyter Notebook, I'm returned with normal text, example

```
'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="pl-PL">\n\n\t<head>\t\n\t\t<title>SPAR |  SPAR &#8211; świeżość i wybór gwarantowane</title>\n\t\t\n\t\t<meta charset=\'UTF-8\'>\n\t\t<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=n
```

What's more, a site that's nearly identical `https://spar.pl/gazetka/eurospar/`, both methods return clean text.

I've tried decoding the result, or using `response.content`, but I couldn't find it helpful. I'm really curious why the problem occurs at all, and how to possibly solve it.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
response.encoding = 'utf-8'
text = response.text
```

Comment: That didn't help, and seemingly didn't change the output